# how to replace text in cell to a data in another table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need you help.

I have a table in MYSQL like this

```
*TABLE1*
id | permission
-- | ----------
a1 | 1,2,3,4,5
v2 | 2,3,4
r1 | 1,3,4,5
b4 |
h7 | 4,5
```

and i have another table

```
*TABLE2*
id | permission
-- | ----------
1  | Allow
2  | Not Allow
3  | Disabled
4  | WOW
5  | Grant
```

I want to select TABLE1 JOIN TABLE2 **BUT:** The new table should be like this

```
*NEW_TABLE*
id | permission
-- | ----------
a1 | Allow,Not Allow,Disabled,WOW,Grant
v2 | Not Allow,Disabled,WOW
r1 | Allow,Disabled,WOW,Grant
b4 |
h7 | WOW,Grant
```

**Is there a way to make it in MYSQL?**

Comment: Nice questions. Seems to me like some text replace from a dictionary. :)

Comment: Nice comment :) But i need an answer :(

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Ofear, I am also waiting for an answer! :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar http://stackoverflow.com/a/12303398/568414

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you could try something along these lines:

this is test setup:

```
mysql> select * from table1;
+------+------------+
| id   | permission |
+------+------------+
| a1   | 1, 2, 3, 4 |
| v2   | 2, 3, 4    |
+------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)



mysql> select * from table2;
+------+------------+
| id   | permission |
+------+------------+
| 1    | Allow      |
| 2    | Not Allow  |
| 3    | Disabled   |
+------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)


mysql> select id, GROUP_CONCAT(t2perm) from (SELECT t1.*, t2.id as t2id, t2.permission as t2perm from table2 t2 cross join table1 t1) crs where INSTR(permission, t2id) > 0 group by id;
+------+--------------------------+
| id   | GROUP_CONCAT(t2perm)     |
+------+--------------------------+
| a1   | Allow,Not Allow,Disabled |
| v2   | Not Allow,Disabled       |
+------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

To explain a bit; first you cross join both tables and that should result in cartesian product, like so:

```
mysql> SELECT * from table2 cross join table1;
+------+------------+------+------------+
| id   | permission | id   | permission |
+------+------------+------+------------+
| 1    | Allow      | a1   | 1, 2, 3, 4 |
| 1    | Allow      | v2   | 2, 3, 4    |
| 2    | Not Allow  | a1   | 1, 2, 3, 4 |
| 2    | Not Allow  | v2   | 2, 3, 4    |
| 3    | Disabled   | a1   | 1, 2, 3, 4 |
| 3    | Disabled   | v2   | 2, 3, 4    |
+------+------------+------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

from that point, just select rows that have one string contained in another (INSTR(permission, t2id) => mapping permissions onto ids), you'll end up with this:

```
mysql> select * from (SELECT t1.*, t2.id as t2id, t2.permission as t2perm from table2 t2 cross join table1 t1) crs where INSTR(permission, t2id) > 0;
+------+------------+------+-----------+
| id   | permission | t2id | t2perm    |
+------+------------+------+-----------+
| a1   | 1, 2, 3, 4 | 1    | Allow     |
| a1   | 1, 2, 3, 4 | 2    | Not Allow |
| v2   | 2, 3, 4    | 2    | Not Allow |
| a1   | 1, 2, 3, 4 | 3    | Disabled  |
| v2   | 2, 3, 4    | 3    | Disabled  |
+------+------------+------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

now just aggregate results with GROUP_CONCAT...

```
select id, GROUP_CONCAT(t2perm) from (SELECT t1.*, t2.id as t2id, t2.permission as t2perm from table2 t2 cross join table1 t1) crs where INSTR(permission, t2id) > 0 group by id;
```

Comment: @Ivica, what does `crs` mean?

Comment: You are welcome :)
@Praveen crs is just an alias that we give to our sub-select (derived table) so we can use it...
(Every derived table must have its own alias)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to work with [cases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html).

But I think what you're trying to do is absolutly wrong. Why would you create such 2 tables?

Comment: You can delete the second table, if it is always the same. I suppose that would be the easiest solution.
You could do it as next: first at all, you will have to split the integers. Then use cases, CASE permission WHEN 1 THEN Allowed, ...

But it is probally more handy to it with PHP. You do a select query, split is with explode and use a case/switch solution or if/elseif/else solution.

Comment: there is a reason why the table build like this :\ And there is no other way to make it

Comment: And the reason is? If you would have normalized your database, you would not have something like this.

Comment: When you dealing with massive amount of data it's better this way.
cos i don't need this data every time, so i have like one million rows per day, and i have 190 permissions, 1m*190=ALOT, so if i'm inserting id's(numbers) and not text, the table is lighter...
every day this one million rows are inserting to an history table..
1m*30(days)*190(permissions)=??? <- TOO BIG

Comment: No ones says you have to save the strings instead of the numbers. The point is, if you normalize your database this still shouldn't happen. In a database design, everything should have it specific meaning (function). So if you define 1 as delete user, 2 as create user,... this should be consistent in your application. You woudldn't need the strings.