# Select rows with JOIN which have 2 conditions on second table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables: `goods` and `cats_goods` (relations table).

Goods: `id`, `name`.

Cats_goods: `good_id`, `cat_id`.

How to select ONLY `goods` which have BOTH `cat_id`=4 AND `cat_id`=24?

Have tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM `goods` AS `g`
JOIN `cats_goods` AS `cg` ON (`g`.`id` = `cg`.`good_id`)
WHERE (`cg`.`cat_id` = 24 AND `cg`.`cat_id` = 4)
```

Query gives 0 results!

**UPD:**
For each `good` there is 1 row in `cats_goods` with `cat_id` = 4 and one row in `cats_goods` with `cat_id` = 24. I only need to select those `goods` which have BOTH conditions match.

**UPD2:**

`goods` table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `goods` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `code` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
  `file` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `preview` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `order` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `selltype_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `xml_date` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `invalid` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `order` (`order`),
  KEY `selltype_id` (`selltype_id`),
  KEY `code` (`code`),
  KEY `invalid` (`invalid`),
  KEY `xml_date` (`xml_date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5014 ;
```

`goods` table data:

```
(4964, '00000001731', 'gold 585', 10000.00, '', '', 0, 2, '', 0),
(4965, '00000001733', 'gold 585', 10000.00, '', '', 0, 2, '', 0),
(4966, '00000001769', 'gold 585', 8000.00, '', '', 0, 2, '', 0),
(4967, '00000001767', 'gold 585', 8000.00, '', '', 0, 2, '', 0),
```

`cats_goods` table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cats_goods` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `good_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `cat_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `good_id` (`good_id`,`cat_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=37530 ;
```

`cats_goods` table data:

```
(37474, 4964, 24),
(37478, 4966, 24),
(37477, 4966, 4),
(37476, 4965, 24),
(37475, 4965, 4),
(37475, 4967, 4),
```

ONLY `goods` 4965 and 4966 must be selected.

Comment: well, your sample datas are not that interesting, as all cases match your request...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM `goods` AS `g`
JOIN `cats_goods` AS `cg1` ON (`g`.`id` = `cg1`.`good_id`)
JOIN `cats_goods` AS `cg2` ON (`g`.`id` = `cg2`.`good_id`)
WHERE (`cg1`.`cat_id` = 24 AND `cg2`.`cat_id` = 4)
```

Comment: @webbandit I put an sqlFiddle in my answer with Nalaka526's solution and mine. It doesn't give the same result, not sure about what you really want as results...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Nalaka526's solution works well on my task. Just have implemented his example on my project. As I've told in question - I only have to select `goods` records which have  both conditions match. Nalaka526's example do exactly this, giving me only those records, not doubling them. Thanks for taking time anyway!

Comment: @webbandit oh no prob, it was just the distinct * in your sample query which made me think to another solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM `goods` AS `g`
JOIN `cats_goods` AS `cg` ON (`g`.`id` = `cg`.`good_id`) 
                          and (`cg`.`cat_id` = 24 OR `cg`.`cat_id` = 4)
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM `goods` AS `g`
JOIN `cats_goods` AS `cg` ON (`g`.`id` = `cg`.`good_id`) 
where `g`.`id` in (24,4)
```

or

```
  SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM `goods` AS `g`
    JOIN `cats_goods` AS `cg1` ON (`g`.`id` = `cg1`.`good_id`) 
                               and (`cg1`.`cat_id` = 24) 
    JOIN `cats_goods` AS `cg2` ON (`g`.`id` = `cg2`.`good_id`) 
                               and (`cg2`.`cat_id` = 4)
```

Comment: `OR` doesn't make my job work. `OR` selects resords which have `cat_id` = 24 OR `cat_id` = 4. I need to select only records which have BOTH conditions match.

Comment: Eah it works too. I'd have to join `cats_goods` table one more time.

Answer (score 0):

This query is rather funny. How can one field, have **two values** at the same time?

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM `goods` AS `g`
JOIN `cats_goods` AS `cg` ON (`g`.`id` = `cg`.`good_id`)
WHERE (`cg`.`cat_id` = 24 AND `cg`.`cat_id` = 4)
```

Change it to `OR` in the `WHERE` condition, buddy.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM `goods` AS `g`
JOIN `cats_goods` AS `cg` ON (`g`.`id` = `cg`.`good_id`)
WHERE (`cg`.`cat_id` = 24 OR `cg`.`cat_id` = 4)
```

If what I asked is possible, can you show the table dump?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but same reason as other answer. Question makes sense, you just gave a bad answer, no reason to be rude.

Comment: i think it's quite clear what the question is (selecting goods in category 1 which are in category 2 at the same time)

Comment: I understand that. But value can realy have it, but only throug relations. I mean for each `good` there is 1 row in `cats_goods` with `cat_id` = 4 and one row in `cats_goods` with `cat_id` = 24

Comment: Hey, @RaphaëlAlthaus, just lemme know, how can there be a single value variable contain two values at the same time? Isn't this stupid? (`cg`.`cat_id` = 24 AND `cg`.`cat_id` = 4)

Comment: @webbandit Can you show the table structure to get a better answer? PS: Am a DBA. That's the reason, I would like to help you and also understand and learn what you are trying to do.

Comment: @PraveenKumar See UPD2 in question.

Comment: I am the downvoter. Changing AND to OR doesn't answer the question. Also your *answer* is more a comment asking for more details.

Comment: @webbandit Will update the answer. Also, please add some dummy data na?

Comment: Please look at question, I've added some data.

Comment: @PraveenKumar http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4adb3/1 - adding one more row with `cat_id` = 24 only breaks all )

Comment: @webbandit I had already come across this kind of SQL, where it is in an array and you need to get the data from it, checking if it exists. That answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12303398/462627 May be this will help you?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.good_id, a.cat_id from cats_goods a inner join goods b on a.good_id=b.id where a.cat_id in (4,24);
```